# Перегрузка __repr__ при динамическом создании класса

Tags: python, ооп

Есть статический метод класса, результат вызова которого возвращает новый класс:

```
class ClassGetter():
    @staticmethod
    def get(classname):

        attributes = dict() # словарь с атрибутами нового класса
        # присваиваем какие-то атрибуты
        ...
        return type(classname, (Base,), attributes)
```

Каким образом я могу динамически определить метод **repr**?
Пробовал примерно так:

```
attributes['__repr__'] = lambda: return getattr(self, name)
```

Очевидно, не получилось...
Как желаемое можно реализовать?

P.S. Base - экземпляр declarative_base SQLAlchemy, так что переопределить у него какие-то методы не совсем здорово...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не работает, потому что вы забыли передать self в качестве аргумента lambda.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 23, 11, 43, 42, 798929)
>>> locdate = type("locdate", (datetime,), {"__repr__": lambda s: s.strftime("%c")})
>>> locdate.now()
Mon Mar 23 11:49:07 2015
```

Comment: Действительно, чет я лажанулся...

Спасибо